# Wireless amplifier antenna

Tags: amplifier, rf, antenna, wifi

There is something like an antenna that works like an amplifier, repeating every signal in the device frequency operation range but wireless.

I mean that this "dumb" active antenna receive every protocol and retransmit all, and of course it need some power to do the job.

I know that specific devices can retransmit the signal using the same protocol (WI-FI repeaters) and also I'm aware of Wireless repeater that work connecting RF cable to the amplifier. Obviously this is not the most elegant solution but the environment that I'm working hasn't too much RF signals.

EDIT:

In short I'm searching for a 2.4 Wireless Repeater.

[image: Wireless repeater]

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a general "receive and retransmit" everything device.
A simple device that tries to do that would also try to retransmit its own signals - instant feedback and the device stops working (possibly with SF movie effects of the device exploding if it had any large amount of power to work with.)

There are repeaters made for various radio systems and protocols, but they always work together with known properties of the signal being used so as to avoid problems.

The simplest example is a repeater for a two-way radio system.  There, the repeater "listens" on one frequency and retransmits on a different one (generally, it transmits on a higher frequency than it receives.)
The devices using the repeater then must "know" to transmit on the frequency the repeater "listens" on, and they must also "know" to "listen" on the frequency the repeater transmits on.

Comment: But someone can create a repeater using a 2.4 GHz tuned radio attached to an antenna and repeat all signals in that frequency?

Comment: No, because if you retransmit on the same frequency you are receiving on then your transmited signal will block your receiver.  Its like connecting a microphone and amplifier to a speaker, then holding the microphone right in front of the speaker.  Squeal, ouch (boom, if the amplifier has enough power.)

Comment: But If you use 2 highly directional antennas, then you can discriminate between receiving and transmitting signals using the same frequency.

Comment: Unfortunately, highly directional antennas still receive from the "back side" and transmit from there as well.  You might do it if you could put a large obstacle between the two antennas, but it would be a lot of trouble and probably not reliable - which is why nobody sells them.

Comment: Ok you are right, there is the figure of front-to-back in radiation pattern, that always exist. But there still a question regarding this. How Wi-Fi repeater works?, because they use DSSS for transmitting/receiving, there are no transmitter frequency or receiver frequency they just spread those signal in channel band. How they discriminate between receiving and transmitting signals? Using internal buffers? I'm a little confused

Comment: They discriminate just like they receive.  The DSSS uses a pseudo random number sequence to do the spreading.  This number is different for each channel.  The repeaters "listen" on one code and transmit on another.  The effect is the same as listening on one frequency and transmitting on another.

Comment: But, as I'm aware, those repeater works in the same channel, they don't translate signals to another channel.

Comment: The work on the same frequency, though not the same logical channel.  If they are managing to use the same channel, then they'd do it by storing and forwarding the data packets.  Listen, store, transmit.

Comment: So they can work in the same channel/frequency but they implement some internal queues/buffers to transmit/receive without colliding. Well after this conversation I have a more clearer vision!